# Groovy ArrayList contains method

Tags: groovy

I'm facing an issue with my groovy script which I cannot figure out why it is happening.

Basically I'm trying to check if my ArrayList:

```
list = [image-ab, image-cd]
```

contains the following string

```
string = 'cd'
```

If I use the 1st condition, it returns "true":

```
if (list[1].contains(string))
```

If I use the 2nd condition, it returns "false":

```
if (list.contains(string))
```

Why is this happening and how must I adapt 2nd condition to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you access the second element of the list `list[1]`, and you call `String.contains(str)` method on the returned string. It returns `true` because indeed `image-cd` contains `cd`. If you do the same with `list[0]`, you would get `false` because the string `image-ab` does not contain `cd`.

In the second case, you call `contains()` method on a list, not an element of the list. This method returns `true` if the list contains the exact `cd` string. And you see `false` because there is no `cd` element in the list.

What you may want to do is to use `list.any()` method that allows you to check if any element of the list matches given predicate. For instance,

```
list.any { el -> el.contains("cd") }
```

will return `true` if at least one element from that list contains `cd`.

The alternative for `any` method is `every`, which expects that every element of the list matches given predicate. For instance,

```
list.every { el -> el.contains("cd") }
```

would return `false` in your case, because `image-ab` does not contain `cd` in the string.